# manipular outra pagina da web via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

é o seguinte, preciso acessar um site e fazer uma pesquisa nele atravéz da minha pagina. estou tentando da seguinte maneira:

```
<html> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"> </script>

<div class="news">  <iframe src="http://alelo.com.br/consulta-saldo-extrato-alelo.html" style="width:100%; height:100%; float:left;" frameborder="0" id = "jones"></iframe> </div>

<input type = "text" id = "piru">

<script> document.getElementById('jones').onload= function() {      var valor = $('#jones').contents().find('#numero').val();  alert(valor);    }

</script> </html>
```

não estou conseguindo fazer nada na pagina dentro do iframe...
Help!

Comment: Se o site não está dentro do mesmo dominio que o teu então não vais conseguir aceder ao site.

Comment: Utilize cURL. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php http://curl.haxx.se/

Comment: Vou dar uma garimpada nesses sites q me passou, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Se o site não está dentro do mesmo dominio que o teu então não vais conseguir aceder ao site. Isso tem a ver com regras de segurança ([CORS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/145493/129)) para impedir que se manipule uma página com JavaScript via iFrame.

O erro que te dá é possivelmente este ([vindo deste exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/w3r2rLca/)):

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a frame with origin "http://alelo.com.br". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.